# SEVERE: Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I am getting below error  when I am trying to run my dynamic web project in tomcat 8.5 This is my first project in Spring

**Error**

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>           org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>             at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>             at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
>             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
>             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
>             at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
>             at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>           Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
>             at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
>             ... 21 more

**my web.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

**my dispatcher-servlet.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping">

        </bean>

        <bean name="/" class="com.learn.spring.controller.BaseController"></bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

I am just trying to print message in a page, do I need applicationContext.xml file? If yes, how can I add it in my project? I read that spring searches [servlet-name]-servlet.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file in the **web.xml** file.
Change your web.xml file adding these line between .

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This is your final web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

You should create dispatcher-servlet.xml file under **WEB-INF** folder

Comment: Hi, i made change but got below error                                           cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'init-param'. One of '{"http://
 xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":enabled, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":async-supported, 
 "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":run-as, "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":security-role-ref, 
 "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee":multipart-config}' is expected.

Comment: I changed a line. Now this is ok. Try with this new web.xml file