# How to debug "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.World" in the Spring framework?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

instead of servlet-dispatcher.xml i'm working with servlet-context.xml & root context.xml

[project /src structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQVnH.png)

[servlet-context.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVZ8T.png)

[root-context.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TH0D.png)

ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL [file:/C:/Program%20Files/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/wtpwebapps/EBoutiqueV3/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/World
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/World
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.createTypeFilter(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parseTypeFilters(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.World
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 34 more

Comment: There is your error `ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.World`. Best include it in the CLASSPATH

Comment: There are millions of questions on Stack Overflow. Consider how useful the site would be if all question authors used a title of "please, i need help!!!".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SEVERE: Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229599/severe-context-initialization-failed-org-springframework-beans-factory-beandefi)

Answer (score 1):

[Solution is here, search before posting.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229599/severe-context-initialization-failed-org-springframework-beans-factory-beandefi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Copy and Paste, so it's an answer

"You have to initialize your dispatcher-servlet.xml file in the web.xml file. Change your web.xml file adding these line between .

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
This is your final web.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

You should create dispatcher-servlet.xml file under WEB-INF folder" - [User Dev4World](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7467246/dev4world) in above topic.

Comment: i will try this right now, thank u very much!!!

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of another one, please comment under the question (you now have enough reputation to do so). At a later stage of reputation you will be able to vote to close questions as duplicates.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work ):